# How to fix/reinstall scikit-learn after installing only for root from source

Tags: package, scikit-learn, fedora20

I've installed scikit-learn 0.15.2 from source on Fedora 20 but only for root.
Here is what I've done:

```
$ sudo yum install gcc gcc-c++ numpy python-devel scipy
$ cd ~/Downloads/
$ git clone https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn
$ cd scikit-learn
$ sudo python setup.py install
```

This installed the software fine but only for root. I forgot about

```
$ python setup.py build
```

before the

```
$ sudo python setup.py install
```

How do I fix this so all users can use scikit-learn? Not even sure where to even start with this. Help is much appreciated.

Comment: A couple of points here: You did not install `0.15.2`, but the development version from github, not the stable version. `scikit-learn` seems to be in fedora repos, any reason why you want to install it manually? Please add `sudo which python` and `which python` to your question.

Comment: Yes, fair point, I was aiming for 0.15.2 but ended up installing latest dev version, it's fine for what I use it for.  The problem with fedora repo is that they only go as far as 0.14.1-5.fc20 for fedora 20. They have newer versions for fedora 21 which is not an option for me. Anyway, I managed to fix.

Answer (score 1):

The fix to this was quite simple. I looked at the output of the commands I used to install it and figured out that the scikit-learn was installed to

```
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/
```

The package worked for root but not for other users so it may be permissions. I checked the permissions on the folder above and as expected only root had access. Other packages in site-packages folder had only read permissions for other users so I thought I'll do the same for this one.

```
$ cd /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/
$ sudo chmod 755 sklearn
$ cd sklearn 
$ sudo find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
$ sudo find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

To make sure it all runs as it should

```
$ nosetests -v sklearn
```

Victory. Hope it helps somebody.